# How to provision one docker container per code branch for CD

Tags: django, docker, bitbucket, devops, continuous-deployment

We are using bitbucket pipelines for CI.

I want to automate the CD flow such that whenever there is a push on a new/existing branch say `feature_abc`(normalized) the latest code of that branch be deployed using a Docker container on my ec2 box and mapped to a subdomain named same as the branch name, i.e. `feature_abc.mydomain.com` for the QA team to start testing that branch's upcoming changes.

How to do it?

Do I have to use fabric in the automation somewhere or docker-compose can do it?

P.S.: I am seasoned Python/Django developer but new to Docker stuff. Have read a lot of dockerfile and docker-compose.yml stuff on the web and getting confused.

Comment: Do you have some continuos integration or devops platform like jenkins, travis, etc ? Are you able to use some of them?

Comment: Do you want to make something like heroku?

Comment: @JRichardsz No, I do not wan to use Jenkins or Travis. No, I am not building something like Heroku :-) I am looking for a staging server setup for my team of developers, wherein when they push code in a branch, it's deployed immediately for the QA team to start testing that branch.

Comment: I mentioned heroku because, when you create a new project called **myapp**, heroku sends you a git url like **https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git** and a public domain like : **http://myapp.herokuapp.com**. Do you want to create something dynamic like heroku only with docker and linux ec2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, though not with Docker tools alone.  You'd roughly need to:

1. Have your CI system tag the image with the branch name
2. Have your CD system pick a port and deploy the image on that port
3. Set up a [network load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) that redirects the "normal" ports for your service (*e.g.*, 80 for HTTP) to the specific port you deployed on
4. Deploy a [Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) DNS record with the branch name pointing at the load balancer
5. When you notice the branch has gone away, undo these steps

I've referenced specific AWS sub-products since you specified EC2, but the same essential sequence should work in any environment (even an on-premises environment using HAProxy and BIND in steps 3 and 4).  (Also, the only thing that's really Docker-specific about this sequence is the packaging system and the unified way to specify a host port for a specific container instance.)

You might consider higher-level tools to manage these things.  [Ansible](https://ansible.com/), for instance, has "modules" to [start Docker containers on remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html), [create AWS NLBs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_network_lb_module.html#elb-network-lb-module), and [create Route 53 records](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/route53_module.html#route53-module).  [Terraform](https://terraform.io/) can manage the cloud resources (but keeping its state consistent with regular automated redeployments can be tricky).

You also might consider a higher-level deployment framework.  This deployment sequence is basically exactly how you access anything on [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html), for instance.  [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is a bigger investment still, but its Service objects have, as a standard option, the ability to [create load balancers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer), and (with an add-on) [create the DNS record for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357311/10008173); but again, "push an image and create a Deployment and Service for it" is the totally ordinary way to deploy anything in Kubernetes and there's nothing particularly special about non-default branches.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's (route 53, load balancer, ...)not quite I was looking for. In fact I am looking at Ansible or Fabric based solution.  I am looking for a staging server setup for my team of developers, wherein when they push code in a branch, it's deployed immediately for the QA team to start testing that branch. Nothing more than that.

Comment: What do you mean?  He told you each step of the process in order to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  When code is pushed to a branch, its deployed immediately for the QA team to start testing that branch.